# Javascript and focus on descendant elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please, check out the JSFiddle:

```
$('#contacts .tab-content').focusout(function () {
    $('#contacts .active').removeClass('active');
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/721vs2b2/)

I have a (Bootstrap 3) panel at the bottom of the page which pops up when I click on its label, and goes back down when I click anywhere else outside of it. To do so, I put focus on the panel and remove the .active class when the focus is lost. The problem is that, if I click on any other focusable element inside of the panel (like inputs or buttons), it also loses the focus and triggers the function. How can I include all elements inside the panel and remove the .active class when none of them is focused?

Comment: I would change the approach: instead of listening the focusout event on the `.tab-content` container to know when you have to close the tab you can listen to the click event on everything else but your `.tab-content` div and its childrens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#contacts > .nav-tabs a').click(function() {
    $('#contacts .tab-content').focus();
    $('#panel').toggleClass('active');
});

$(document).click(function(e){
    if(!$(event.target).closest( ".tab-content" ).length && !$(event.target).closest( ".nav-tabs a" ).length){
        $('#panel').removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

Check this once

Comment: This works great! Only a minor flaw: the panel doesn't close when clicking the empty space at right or left of the label.
Could you please explain me what does "$(event.target).closest( "#contacts" ).length" actually mean?

Comment: @DanieleColonnese I just updated the if condition to check the anchor element rather than the UL. 

closest('#contacts') will find weather the parents has contacts or not.